# Jointtype of google_map_flutter not working in IOS

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios, flutter-ios

Im using [google_map_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) for implementing map,but i need to use the property jointype of polyline and i changed the jointype to round but it doesnot make any change. The exact use of polyline is for i need to curve the joints of polyline whenever turn occurs.

```
 Polyline(
        polylineId: const PolylineId('seg1'),
        points: routes,
        jointType: JointType.round,
        geodesic: false,
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: 10,
      )
```